# Database error in migrating from JSON

Tags: migrations

I had a migration that was working a few months ago on an 8.6 site before the JSON API module was part of core. Nothing has changed on the site I'm migrating to or from, but I'm now getting the following SQL error:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'sourceid1' at row 1: INSERT INTO

{migrate_map_articles}
```

I don't have a column `sourceid1` and it's not clear what it's doing in Drupal's migration module. Any idea what could be happening here?

For reference, I'm using this article: https://www.lullabot.com/articles/pull-content-from-a-remote-drupal-8-site-using-migrate-and-json-api

Comment: Source ID refers to the incoming source id in a migration

Comment: ...which is missing from the row that's trying to be imported, hence the attempt to insert a blank string into the mapping table. To clarify, `sourceid1` is a column in a table that the migrate module creates, it's not a column in your migration data

Comment: I'm confused. So it's not from my data but from the module and it's missing? How?

Comment: No, the data comes from your migration source. The migration module can't find a value for the column you've set as the identifier, whether thats for one row or multiple it's not possible to say from here, so it can't continue

Comment: What do you mean by identifier? Identifier of what? I've added the article I've been following for reference.

Comment: Every record you import has to have one or more identifiers, so each can be uniquely identified. This is used in a `migrate_map_<migration_name>` table to map the source ID (from the content being imported) to the ID of newly created content in the target site. The error is telling you that said identifier cannot be found/reconciled with your current migration config. I'm afraid I can't give you any more info than that without being in front of the code